# Gulp watch stop after I install run-sequence

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I used to have "gulp watch" working fine. My "gulp watch" no longer run after I do **npm install run-sequence**.  Running **gulp** work fines. It looks like any filesystem change never trigger "gulp watch" for run.

Below are my gulpfile and NPM packages.

I used to have "gulp watch" working fine. My "gulp watch" no longer run after I do **npm install run-sequence**.  Running **gulp** work fines. It looks like any filesystem change never trigger "gulp watch" for run.

Below are my gulpfile and NPM packages.

```
const del = require('del');
const gulp = require('gulp');

const ext_replace = require('gulp-ext-replace');
const nunjucks = require('gulp-nunjucks');
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
var sequence  = require('run-sequence');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// delete dist folder
gulp.task('clean', function(){
     return del.sync(['dist/**']);
});

// compile boostrap
gulp.task('compile-boostrap', function(done) {
    spawn('npm', ['run', 'dist'], { cwd: 'src/bootstrap/', stdio: 'inherit', shell: true })
    .on('close', done);
});

// copy Bootstrap
gulp.task('copy-bootstrap', () =>
  gulp.src('src/bootstrap/dist/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/bootstrap/dist'))
);

// copy boostrap vendor
gulp.task('copy-bootstrap-vendor', () =>
  gulp.src('src/bootstrap/assets/js/vendor/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/bootstrap/dist/js/vendor'))
);

// css task
gulp.task('copy-css', () =>
  gulp.src('src/css/*.css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
);

// js task
gulp.task('copy-js', () =>
   gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
);

// image task
gulp.task('copy-images', () =>
   gulp.src('src/images/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
);

gulp.task('sass', () =>
   gulp.src('src/css/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({sourcemap: true}))
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
);

// bower components
gulp.task('copy-bower', () =>
   gulp.src('src/bower_components/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/bower_components'))
);


//template data
// today
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

// item list
item_list = []
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    item = {'name':'My Item',
               'location': 'NY, NY',
               'rating': 4,
               'img_src': 'images/no_image.png'};
    item_list.push(item);
}

// suggest list
suggest_list = []
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    item = {'name':'Suggested ittem',
                'location': 'NY, NY',
                'rating': 4,
                'img_src': 'images/no_image.png'};
    suggest_list.push(item);
}

// comment list
comment_list = []
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    comment = {'username':'Comment Username',
               'comment': 'This is my comment',
               'date': today,
               'img_src': 'images/no_image.png'};
    comment_list.push(comment);
}

// review list
review_list = []
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    review = {'username':'Review Username',
              'review': 'This is my review',
              'date': today,
              'img_src': 'images/no_image.png'};
    review_list.push(review);
}

// user
user = {'username': "My Name",
        'email': 'my@email.com',
        'img_src': 'images/no_image.png'}

// template task
gulp.task('njk', () =>
   gulp.src('src/*.njk')
        .pipe(nunjucks.compile({'comment_list': comment_list,
                                'item_list':item_list,
                                'suggest_list': suggest_list,
                                'review_list': review_list,
                                'user': user}))
        .pipe(ext_replace('.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);


// "gulp watch" from command line
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*', function (event) {
          sequence('clean',
                   'copy-bootstrap',
                   'copy-bootstrap-vendor',
                   'copy-css',
                   'copy-js',
                   'copy-images',
                   'sass',
                   'njk',
                   'copy-bower');
    });
});


// "gulp" from command line
gulp.task('default', function (done) {
    sequence('clean',
             'compile-boostrap',
             'copy-bootstrap',
             'copy-bootstrap-vendor',
             'copy-css',
             'copy-js',
             'copy-images',
             'sass',
             'njk',
             'copy-bower',
             done);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "templates",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-exec": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-ext-replace": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-nunjucks": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.0",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "npm": "^5.5.1",
    "nunjucks": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: You have no return statements in your tasks.

Comment: @Mark, I added back the "return" keyword, but it still doesn't work